# expected value before product is less than N

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Take a Number N between 0 and 1 not inclusive. Then start selecting numbers randomly between 0 and 1 non inclusive. What is the expected amount of numbers I need before My product is less than or equal to N? Using the definition of expected value and some integration I have a formula based on integration and extrapolation of patters but I’m not sure if it’s correct or simplified
[here is my formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9i1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as as Markov chain with states $s_0$ and $s_1$. Once you sample a number in the interval $(0,p)$, you are done. Hence:
$$
m_{0,1} = 1 + (1-p)m_{0,1}\\
m_{0,1} = \frac{1}{p}
$$
where $m_{i,j}$ is the mean first hitting time of state $1$ if you start in state $0$.